# Float too large for the page Warning

Tags: tables, warnings

I get the "Float too large for the page" warning and I am interested if I can ignore it. The table I have is indeed huge but it fits just exactly like it should on one page (aesthetically looks beautiful), but I could not get rid of the error. Any suggestions? Since the table is huge and also the information in it is for internal use only, unfortunately I cannot post it here.

Comment: It's just a warning message, *not* an error message. If you believe that the page with the table on it looks fine, I would declare victory and move on.

Comment: if you end the figure with `\vspace{- however much the float is too large by}` then the output won't change but latex will stop moaning at you as you have explictly said the figure should stick in to teh bottom margin by that amount

Answer (score 1):

*Community Answer*

Following David's comment, end the figure with

```
\vspace{- however much the float is too large by}
% For example
\vspace{-20pt}
```

This will not change the output but remove the warning because you now explicitly tell LaTeX that the figure should have this spacing.